# Elasticsearch : Can I paging term aggregation and top hits by from and size?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

Is there any solution in my query with `terms` aggregation  **from**:

```
{
    "size":0
    ,"aggs":{
        "packageid":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"packageId",
                "size":10,
                "from":10
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_tag_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "version": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want `from`, `size` in `terms` aggregation to paging top 10 lastest version package start index `10` and end index `20`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control the elasticsearch aggregation results with From / Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038131/how-to-control-the-elasticsearch-aggregation-results-with-from-size)

Comment: 1 year, 8 months ago & 4 months ago, this question has duplicate my question?

Comment: It's not a race lol, the flag is only intended to direct other people who might have the same question to an answer that may help them

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, aggregations currently
[don't support paging](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915), so you'd have to implement it client side

Answer (score 0):

Since pagination over aggregation is not supported.So you can fetch all the buckets during aggregation and then on client side handle the pagination.
You need to modify your query to "size":100000.
Fetch all the buckets and apply pagination in service layer.