# How to control the elasticsearch aggregation results with From / Size?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, elasticsearch-plugin

I have been trying to add pagination in elasticsearch term aggregation. In query we can add the pagination like,

```
 {
    "from": 0, // to add the start to control the pagination
    "size": 10,
    "query": { } 
 }
```

this is pretty clear, but when I want to add pagination to aggregation, I read a lot about it, but I couldn't find anything, My code looks like this,

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 20
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_tag_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to create pagination with a function or any other suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregation + sorting +pagination in elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776582/aggregation-sorting-pagination-in-elastic-search)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you probably want partitions. [From the docs:](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions)

> Sometimes there are too many unique terms to process in a single request/response pair so it can be useful to break the analysis up into multiple requests. This can be achieved by grouping the field’s values into a number of partitions at query-time and processing only one partition in each request.

Basically you add `"include": { "partition": n, "num_partitions": x },`, where `n` is the page and `x` is the number of pages.

Unfortunately this feature was added fairly recently. If the tags can be believed on the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21487) which spawned this feature, you'll need to be on at least Elasticsearch 5.2 or better.